# Issues with Spring MVC @RequestMappings and redirects

Tags: redirect, spring-mvc, post-redirect-get

I am experiencing problems with Spring MVC `@RequestMapping`s and redirects.

I have the following method in one of my controllers:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/activateEmail/{token}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html")
    public String activateEmail(@PathVariable("token") String token) {
        preferencesService.activateEmail(token);
        signinService.signin(memberRepository.findByToken(token));
        return "redirect:preferences/email";//HERE
}
```

However, when the user is initially located at:

```
http://localhost:8080/bignibou/preferences/email
```

the above "redirect directive" redirects to:

```
http://localhost:8080/bignibou/activateEmail/preferences/email
```

Whereas I expected it to redirect me to:

```
http://localhost:8080/bignibou/preferences/email
```

In order for the desired effect to be achieved I had to resort to the following ugly hack:

```
return "redirect:../preferences/email";//HERE
```

Can anyone please suggest a better practice?

Comment: did you try "redirect:/preferences/email"

Comment: Of course I should have tried that... Thanks a lot Arun!!

Comment: I've updated the comment as an answer so that you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is `"redirect:/preferences/email"`